# How to make successful calls to execCommand('copy') from React mouse event handler?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Summary**

I wrote a small method to copy text to the clipboard, which works (in Chrome, Edge and IE11) if I trigger the code from a simple HTML button event handler like this:

```
class MyController
{
    constructor()
    {
        ...
        testButton_.onclick = (event: MouseEvent) => { this.onTestButtonClicked(event); }
        ...
    }

    onTestButtonClicked(event: MouseEvent)
    {
        Utilities.copyTextToClipboard("Testing the clipboard functionality!");
    }

    ...
}
```

where testButton_ is an HTMLButtonElement.

Now, when I call this same method from the event handler of a React component, the method fails in Edge and Chrome, but succeeds in IE11.
It appears that the `document.execCommand("copy")` call returns false.

*Can someone please explain me how I can make a successful call to `document.execCommand("copy")` from within a React mouse event handler?*

Note: I did read various other posts on here and on https://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html#dfn-the-copy-command but since this is all called from within a user (right-)click event, I would expect this to work (as it does with the plain HTML event handler) also in React.

**Details**

(I'm using React and TypeScript by the way)

This is what's in the React component:

```
class DashboardItemComponent extends React.Component<DashboardItemComponentProps, DashboardItemComponentState>
{
    static defaultProps: DashboardItemComponentProps = {
        projectName: ""
    };

    constructor(props: DashboardItemComponentProps)
    {
        super(props);

        this.onContextMenu = this.onContextMenu.bind(this);
    }

    render(): JSX.Element
    {
        return (
            <div onContextMenu={this.onContextMenu}>
                <div className="inner">
                    <header>
                        <h2>{this.props.projectName}</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div>more text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    protected onContextMenu(e: React.MouseEvent)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        Utilities.copyTextToClipboard("testing 1 2 3");
    }
}
```

And this is what's in the copyTextToClipboard method of my Utilities class (parts gathered from other posts on SO and this code does work fine):

```
static copyTextToClipboard(text: string): boolean
{
    // Find the dummy text area or create it if it doesn't exist
    const dummyTextAreaID = "utilities-copyTextToClipboard-hidden-TextArea-ID";
    let dummyTextArea: HTMLTextAreaElement = document.getElementById(dummyTextAreaID) as HTMLTextAreaElement;
    if (!dummyTextArea)
    {
        console.log("Creating dummy textarea for clipboard copy.");

        let textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textArea.id = dummyTextAreaID;

        // Place in top-left corner of screen regardless of scroll position.
        textArea.style.position = "fixed";
        textArea.style.top = "0";
        textArea.style.left = "0";

        // Ensure it has a small width and height. Setting to 1px / 1em
        // doesn't work as this gives a negative w/h on some browsers.
        textArea.style.width = "1px";
        textArea.style.height = "1px";

        // We don't need padding, reducing the size if it does flash render.
        textArea.style.padding = "0";

        // Clean up any borders.
        textArea.style.border = "none";
        textArea.style.outline = "none";
        textArea.style.boxShadow = "none";

        // Avoid flash of white box if rendered for any reason.
        textArea.style.background = "transparent";

        document.querySelector("body").appendChild(textArea);
        dummyTextArea = document.getElementById(dummyTextAreaID) as HTMLTextAreaElement;

        console.log("The dummy textarea for clipboard copy now exists.");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("The dummy textarea for clipboard copy already existed.")
    }

    // Set the text in the text area to what we want to copy and select it
    dummyTextArea.value = text;
    dummyTextArea.select();

    // Now execute the copy command
    try
    {
        let status = document.execCommand("copy");
        if (!status)
        {
            console.error("Copying text to clipboard failed.");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Text copied to clipboard.");
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.log("Unable to copy text to clipboard in this browser.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not working even once ? or is it working for the first time and then its failing ?

Comment: It works always for the plain HTML event handler, and for the React event handler in IE11, but not even once for the React event handler in Edge or Chrome. It does create the textarea though and selects the text, but then fails on the executeCommand (using Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94).

Comment: Is it failing because of a re-render occurring after you create the dummytextarea? You may want to add a "ID" to your JSX component to help in the case of a re-render (it's good practice to have a unique id for all JSX components).

Comment: It looks like `document.execCommand()` might have [limited support across different browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @SteveB Wouldn't that mean that the dummmytextarea would get re-created on each call to copyTextToClipboard then? I don't see that happening.

Comment: @TPorter Yes, I saw that. The thing is that document.execCommand() does works fine in all 3 browsers I mentioned, only not when it's called from my React event handler method. That's what my question is really about.
I read in different places that there are time limits for async calls, but I'm not sure what to do in this case of a React mouse event handler (as it's clearly not taking 1 second for the action to happen)...

Comment: KoenT_X have you tried using the react package react-copy-to-clipboard  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-copy-to-clipboard to see if it resolves your issues. It may not work for your example, but it's worth a shot to see if is resolves some of your issues.

Comment: I put together a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/93339/) using your `copyTextToClipboard()` code, and I'm not having issues in any browser.

Comment: @TPorter Thanks for taking the time to set this up! This indeed worked.
However, in my use case, I am using the onConextMenu event (for right-mouse-button-clicking), and when I change your code to also add that event, it turns out that that doesn't work... 
Here is the adjusted code: https://jsfiddle.net/fna59r5c/14/ 
I tried this in Chrome and Edge, and both fail with "Copying text to clipboard failed." when right-clicking. I also tried in IE11, but that gave an error when loading the JSFiddle code (but I know that IE11 is not a problem in my code).

Comment: I supplied an answer after getting it to work on a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0q8y9xpy/  However, on both Safari and Chrome on osX (mac), I got, "Unable to copy text to clipboard in this browser". You may need to ask permission (temporarily) on some browsers and os's to get this to work in the real world).